# How to rewrite my code in Scheme without saving status information in structures?

Tags: graph, scheme, racket

I was playing in Scheme and I was trying to create a predicate which would tell me, if there is a path between two vertices in a given graph. My program basicaly uses queue to figure it out. I use BFS to traverse through the graph and I add all adjoining vertices to the queue and if my sought value is in said queue, I return #t. But this solution requires using data structure to store all the info and I am aware, that passing the queue between multiple functions is not ideal. How can I change my code without using the queue and make it more clean? You can see my code below.

I used this aproach: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-vertices-in-a-given-graph/

```
(require data/queue)
(define-struct graph (vertices edges))
(define-struct vertice (name visited))
(define-struct edge (start-vertice end-vertice length))

;I create data for testing here
(define vertices-list2
  (list (make-vertice 0 0)
        (make-vertice 1 0)
        (make-vertice 2 0)
        )
  )

(define edges-list2
  (list (make-edge 0 1 0)
        (make-edge 1 2 0)
        )
  )

;Const for marking a vertice as visited
(define VISITED 99999)

(define (reachable? X Y G)
  (let ((q (make-queue)))
    (cond
      [(empty? (graph-edges G)) #f]
      [(= X Y) #t]
      [else (bfs-graph X Y G q) ]
      )
    )
  )

(define (bfs-graph X Y G q)
  (cond
    [(not(eq? (vertice-visited (find-vertice X (graph-vertices G))) VISITED))
     (begin
       (set-vertice-visited! (find-vertice X (graph-vertices G)) VISITED)
       (find-adj X (graph-edges G) q)
       (cond
         [(queue-empty? q) #f]
         [(memq Y (queue->list q)) #t]
         [else (bfs-graph (dequeue! q) Y G q)]
         )
       )
     ]
    [(queue-empty? q) #f]
    [else (bfs-graph (dequeue! q) Y G q)]
    )
  )

(define (find-vertice V vertice-list)
  (cond
    [(empty? vertice-list) (error 'find-vertice "Graph does not contain given vertice")]
    [(eq? V (vertice-name (car vertice-list))) (car vertice-list)]
    [else (find-vertice V (cdr vertice-list))]
    )
  )

(define (find-adj V edge-list q)
  (cond
    [(empty? edge-list) q]
    [(eq? V (edge-start-vertice (car edge-list)))
     (begin
       (enqueue! q (edge-end-vertice (car edge-list)))
       (find-adj V (cdr edge-list) q))
     ]
    [else (find-adj V (cdr edge-list) q)]
    )
  )

;Run
(define G (make-graph vertices-list2 edges-list2))
;Predicate call
(reachable? 0 1 G)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you don't want to pass the queue along.

However one way to avoid passing the queue is to make both the queue and the helper functions local to bfs-graph.

```
(define (bfs-graph X Y G)
  (define q (make-queue))
  (define (find-vertice V vertice-list) ...)
  (define (find-adj V edge-list) ...)
  (cond
    [(not(eq? (vertice-visited (find-vertice X (graph-vertices G))) VISITED))
     ...]
   ... as-before ...))
```

PS: One vertex, two vertices

Comment: I was told that my aproach is not using a functional aproach and that there is a much cleaner way of solving this issue without saving all the data in the queue. So my question is more like "how can I have the same functionality but with lists instead of queues?".

Comment: You can use two lists (stacks) to implement a queue. See https://programmingpraxis.com/2013/11/08/two-stacks-make-a-queue/ or the original article: http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp95queue.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is definitely useful. However if I put the queue implementation into my code, it won't make it cleaner right? I wonder if there is a different approach to my solution without the queues whatsoever.

Comment: It will be a different algorithm (different order of traversal), but it might be simpler to use a stack (i.e. a plain list) than queue.